# jQuery.ScrollTo - How to add a class to the navigation item when I scroll to a certain anchor?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a one page website that uses jQuery.ScrollTo with a layout like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#section1" id="item01">Menu Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2" id="item02">Menu Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section3" id="item03">Menu Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#section4" id="item04">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="section1">
...content...
</div>
<div id="section2">
...content...
</div>
<div id="section3">
...content...
</div>
<div id="section4">
...content...
</div>
```

The behavior I want to reach is that when I scroll to a certain div without clicking the links in the menu the class of the anchor related to that div to change.

Is this possible using the jQuery.scrollTo script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) has that built in. But another plugin called [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) would give you that functionality.

It would end up looking like this:

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
  alert('Top of thing hit top of viewport.');
});
```

Comment: Is it supposed to work like that ? 

$('#section3').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#item03').addClass('active');
});